# How to set Google Form response destination to two different spreadsheets in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Each group has a Google Form to fill out. The responses for each group form is sent to a spreadsheet for each group. I want to have a "Master Spreadsheet" that would collect all responses from all the groups. In Google Apps Scripts, I tried:

```
form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, responseSpreadsheet.getId());
form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, masterSpreadsheet.getId());
```

The responses were only sent to "masterSpreadsheet" and "responseSpreadsheet" got ignored.

Comment: You can only have one destination.  How about getting data from one spreadsheet to another?

Answer (score 3):

I briefly looked for documentation explicitly stating that Google Forms only support one *external* destination, but didn't find any. However, you can assume this from the UI only supporting one as well [`getDestinationId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getdestinationid) only returning a single ID.

Probably the most straightforward approach to getting the responses to another spreadsheet is to use a [form submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) on the primary destination spreadsheet. That trigger provides the `values` property in the event object, which you can simply pass to [`appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents).

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const alternateDestinations = [
    { url: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/edit', sheetName: 'Sheet1' }
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < alternateDestinations.length; i++) {
    let dest = alternateDestinations[i];
    SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(dest.url).getSheetByName(dest.sheetName).appendRow(e.values);
  }
}
```

A more complex approach would be to use the [form submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) on the form itself. Rather than setting a specific spreadsheet destination, you could have it write the responses to all of the spreadsheets you specify.